# How to ignore some attributes of an @Embeddable inside an @Entity?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two `@Entity` **A** and **B**, and I have an `@Embeddadble` `Address` as follows:

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    private String line1;
    private String line2;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class A {
    @Id private long id;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="line1", column=@Column(name="TABLE_A_LINE1")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="line2", column=@Column(name="TABLE_A_LINE2"))
    })
    private Address address;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id private long id;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="line1", column=@Column(name="TABLE_B_LINE1"))
        // don't want line2 in B
    })
    private Address address;
}
```

The table for `@Entity` **B** has no `TABLE_B_LINE2` column, but I still want to embed `Address` in **B** because it makes sense in my model. The mapping above doesn't work for **B** because the SQLs generated by Hibernate always reference line2 column.

If I put `@Transient` in `Address.line2`, it works for `@Entity` **B**, but now `@Entity` **A** loses its capacity to query, insert and update line2.

Do you think it's possible to selectively ignore some attributes of an `@Embeddable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not remodel your `Address` slightly as follows:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Embeddable
public class Address {
  /* does not include address line 2 */
}
```

Then extend it as follows:

```
@Embeddable
public class ExtendedAddress extends Address {
  private String line2;
}
```

Then use `Address` in your Entity **B** and then use `ExtendedAddress` in your Entity **A**.

Comment: Interesting. And makes the object model seem more correct.

Comment: yet it can't have MappedSuperclass AND Embeddable. One or the other. Also the JPA spec doesn't define support for inherited Embeddable objects (i.e discriminators etc that would be needed to identify their type)

Comment: @NeilStockton I did exactly as Naros said, except for the "MappedSuperclass". It worked for the "B" entity. Didn't test A yet.

Comment: @NeilStockton It most certainly works with Hibernate.

Comment: @Gustavo I'm talking of the JPA spec. If you want to use non-portable code then that's your decision, but you should be aware that this is what you're doing. So does Hibernate add a discriminator to determine what type of Address is embedded??? If the answer is no then no it won't work reliably for basic retrieval. End of the day it is non-portable.